# Is the fleet only available by playing online?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag, assassins-creed-4-kenways-fleet

When I tried to access my fleet in the Captain's quarters I was prompted to sign into xboxlive (I have no internet access on my Xbox so this isn't possible for me). When I'm taking over hostile ships I sometimes have the option to send the ship to my fleet.

Is there any way I can use the fleet feature *without* being on live, or is that whole part of the game unavailable to me making "send to fleet" a waste of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed only available if you're playing online. This is for 1 main reason.

1. You send your fleet on missions that take a set amount of time (with variations depending on the speed of the boat). The game clocks this time using the online server. For example, some missions take 24 hours to complete. But you don't need to play the game for 24 hours, just wait until 24 hours pass on the server clock.

Sadly, they designed the game so you can't get 100% completion without being online. Here are things you'll miss.

1. 3 treasure maps, at least 1 of which contains a plan you need to fully upgrade your ship.
2. Appearance items for your ship (figurehead, etc).
3. Additional non-functioning items (outfit for Edward, etc)

**UPDATE**

I think there is also a trophy (at least on PS4) or an Abstergo challenge to unlock all of the fleet locations.

Comment: Thankfully the only Online-only upgrade is the single least useful upgrade - exploding barrel storage. Who uses these things?

Comment: Yeah. I think I've used them once - on the legendary ship where there are 2 of them. But I am a 100% maniac, so I NEEDED the treasure maps and (useless) gear. LOL

Answer (score 2):

Kennway's Fleet is only available online. It encourages "helping" your friends like Facebook games do. You can speed up their ships by pressing a button when selecting them. Therefore, this portion of the game is only available if you are online.

Answer (score 2):

The [IGN Wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/Kenway's_Fleet) states that you do need an Internet connection even if you do not play with friends.  It will require the UPlay code provided with the game, but not a UPlay account to use.

The good news is the only resources that carry over into the game are Reales earned.  The other resources in that game are just for upgrading your fleet or completing more fleet missions.

You can also unlock some art and treasure maps.  Art shows up in your house at the Pirate Cove.  Most of the treasure maps just lead to more chests with Reales.  The notable exception to this is the plan for Elite Fire Barrel Storage, and I personally never found Fire Barrels to be terribly useful in combat.

So yes, you need an Internet connection to access Kenway's fleet, but aside from some vanity items and the Elite Fire Barrel Storage you are only missing out on another source of income and a mini-game.  This has no affect on the story.